# Dynamically loaded AngularJs code via ASP MVC are not bound

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm loading a Partial view which contains AngularJS code, using the code below:

```
http.post("/Admin/LoadPartial", {
path: "~/Views/Admin/Urchin/Modals/_ChangeHero.cshtml",
model: self.newID
}).then(function (res) {

//res.data is the .cshtml                       
var element = angular.element(res.data);
var modal = $compile(element)(scope);
self.newSlides.push({
    "ID": self.newID,
    "Data": self.newData,
    "Modal": modal.html()
});

scope.$emit("ngRepeatFinished");
Notify.Show("Saul goodman", "notice");});
```

This is how I render the partial:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in h.newSlides" 
     ng-bind-html="item.Modal | to_trusted" id="Hey-{{item.ID}}"></div>
```

And the filter:

```
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}])
```

**The problem:**

The rendered partial loads as HTML, but it contains code like this:

```
<button id="bgProg-@Model" class="progress-button" ng-click="h.EditBG()">
```

where `h` is the controller that loaded the `.cshtml`, and no click event is bound to the button.

Any ideas as to where I'm doing things wrong are greatly appreciated.

---

**Progress**

Thank you @user1620220 for the response. 
I added this right after `Notify.Show(..` :

```
timeout(function () {
var what = document.getElementById("Hey-" + self.newID);
var element = angular.element(what);
var modal = $compile(element)(scope);
what.innerHTML = content;}, 0, false);
```

and still no bindings are happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$compile` to generate a compiled node, but then you are calling `html()` to convert the node back to a string. `ng-bind-html` then converts the string into an uncompiled node and adds it to the DOM.

<strike>Instead, just pass `res.data` to `ng-bind-html`, allow the digest loop to run, then compile the in-situ DOM node.</strike>

**Edit**: After reading your edit, it occurred to me you need to use the `cloneAttachFn` returned by `$compile`. Here is my new proposed solution:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in h.newSlides"> 
    <div id="Hey-{{item.ID}}"><!--place holder--></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var linkFn = $compile(res.data);
timeout(function () {
    self.newSlides.forEach((slide) => {
        var what = document.getElementById("Hey-" + slide.ID);
        linkFn(scope,(clone) => {
            what.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, what);
        });           
    });        
}, 0, false);
```

Comment: thank you for the response, taught me an important thing as well as giving me hope,. I updated the question.

Comment: I did as you said and Everything works! Thank you so much! It's awesome!